# how to make my code only alert 'gggg' , can not delete the first Statement using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, code-coverage

this is my code :

```
<input type="button" value="edit" id="edit"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input').click(function(){
            alert('sss')
        })
    $('input').click(function(){
            alert('gggg')
        })
</script>
```

and when i click the button, it alert twitce,

so how to Cover the first Statement  ,

thanks

Comment: You question isn't clear; you are specifying click event two times for the input selector and then saying it alerts two times....

Comment: i want it only alert once time , alert 'gggg', not alert 'ssss'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`jQuery.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method to remove any click event listener from specified elements and then bind a new one:

```
$("input").unbind("click").click(function() {
    alert("This is the only listener bound to this element");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove this from the `<script>` block

```
$('input').click(function(){
    alert('sss')
})
```

so that you are left with only

```
<input type="button" value="edit" id="edit"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input').click(function(){
        alert('gggg');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Read the question title again.  He cannot remove that line.

Comment: If they cannot delete code from the file, how are they going to add to it?

Comment: I'm assuming that the lines are actually in two separate .JS files, one which he can modify, and one which he can't.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').click(function(){ 
        alert('gggg') ;
        return false;
    })
```

or

```
$('input').click(function(event){ 
        alert('gggg') ;
        event.stopPropagation();
    })
```

Now to completely get rid of that event handler, you could unbind it:

```
$('input').click(function(){
        alert('sss')
    });
// :
// :

$('input').unbind("click");
$('input').click(function(){
        alert('gggg')
    })
```

Comment: I think the preferred jQuery way is to included an `event` in the function arguments then call `event.preventDefault();` rather than `return false;`